# Importing XML files to Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a large amount of XML files that I transfer via ftp to an azure website folder on a daily basis. I currently use c# to transfer the data to azure sql server tables. However, it is extremely slow.

Is there a way I can run an Azure SQL job to bulk import these files and if so, how do I access the files in the web apps folder?

I know how to do this on a standard SQL server with XML files residing on a share drive but am unsure how to do this in azure.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we do not support any T-SQL interface to read files from blob store or container. So you have to push the data from outside of SQL Server.

One option is to use Azure Automation to run your code periodically or based on a schedule. See post below on how to use Azure Automation:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/automation-manage-sql-database/